# twitter url tweet no longer functioning

Tags: html, url, twitter

I have been using the same function to generate twitter status URL's, but now when they are clicked, no status appears in the box in twitter.

The following is an example of what my URL's look like (using copy link location)

http://twitter.com/home?status=Just%20reading%20%27H.M%20Naqvi%20wins%20the%20DSC%20Prize%20for%20South%20Asian%20Literature%27%20http%3A%2F%2Ftinyurl.com%2F4c5mrex%20%40%09SthAsianLitFest%20

Comment: I tried this its working fine which browser your are using ?

Comment: just tried in Chrome, no darts. What browser are you using?

Comment: Does seem broken on Chrome. Use this instead? http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=foo

Comment: turn this into an answer!! It needs ticking!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does seem broken on Chrome.

Use this instead? http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=foo